# How to change horizontal spacing before section number

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

How do i change the small horizontal spacing that is present before a section number?

I have used the command `\titlespacing` from package `titlesec` to set the left spacing to 0, but it is still present.
Small example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont \bfseries}{\hspace{0mm} \thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\section{Section title}

Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet Lorem ispum dolor sit amet 

\end{document}
```

If you look at the output, "Section title" is aligned to the second line of text perfectly, whereas the section number "1" is slightly moved to the right.

Comment: Use only `\thesection`, not `\hspace{0mm} \thesection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your definition of `\titleformat`, the "real" space between

```
\hspace{0mm} \thesection}{1em}{}
```

is interpreted by latex as ... a *space*.  just get rid of it:

```
\hspace{0mm}\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: `\hspace{0mm}` can also be deleted.

Comment: Oh my, you are right. I add spaces everywhere for better readability, but in this case it shot me in the face.